# Unable to use Iterator for a MAP to PRINT STRING. (able to print int)

Tags: string, visual-c++, iterator, cout

I tried printing a string in the MAP using iterator but I am getting an error.

Program -

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<map>
#include<string.h>
#include<unordered_map>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
std::map<int,std::string>mymap;
std::map<int,std::string>::iterator it;

mymap.insert(make_pair(10, "sid"));
mymap.insert(make_pair( 20, "sam"));

for (it = mymap.begin(); it != mymap.end(); it++)
{
    //printf("%s \n", it->second);
    std::cout <<*it->second << std::endl;
}
system("pause");
_getch;

}
```

Error list

```
1.Error C2679   binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand 
 the operand of type 'std:: string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)  
2.Error (active) no operator "<<" matches these operands
```

I was able to print the int properly. I am unable to print the STRING. Please suggest a solution.

Comment: When you're already using `using namespace std`, I don't understand why you are using `std::` everywhere redundantly?

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you access the object pointed to by the iterator.

Just use `cout<< it->second<<endl;`.

All the errors are then automatically resolved.

P.S. Refer to my comment on your question.